# How can we export the full copy of PRODUCT with all the API's associated to it

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way by exporting the PRODUCT it gives the full definition of it including the with API's and policies associated with that PRODUCT.

That way i can make only two calls to export the complete product and import the complete product somewhere else.

Is there any other best practices to minimize below number of calls to export and import

1. Make GET call(s) to REST Management API to export the different API’s from one subscription.
2. Make GET call(s) to REST Management API to export the policies from API’s. (Unfortunately,  Exporting API’s will not export policies associated with it).
3. Make PUT call(s) to REST Management API to import the different API’s to another subscription.
4. Make PUT call(s) to REST Management API to set the policies associated to API’s.
5. Make GET call(s) to REST Management API to export the different Product’s from one subscription.
6. Make GET call(s) to REST Management API to get the list  of API’s associated with PRODUCT.
7. Make PUT call(s) to REST Management API to create the Product in another subscription.
8. Make PUT call(s) to REST Management API to add the API’s to Product.

Comment: What is the "PRODUCT"?

Comment: The product is the "group" to which an api can be added, there is a starter and an unlimited product default in api management, each product can have different policies

Comment: A product contains one or more APIs.
For example Starter and unlimited are the PRODUCTS that come with the initial subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO Recommendation or any other way to reduce the above effort at this time.

Comment: Have you tried using GIT to move the Api Configuration between instances.  [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-configuration-repository-git/)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want to clone your second service with the first one, you can use backup restore
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore/
What it does essentially is copy all your metadata (Apis/Products/Subscriptions) to another service.

Or

You can create scripts to export your apis using the Azure Powershell commandlets
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613477.aspx
and then add it to the second service using the Import commandlets
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613484.aspx

Comment: Instead of using the PowerShell commandlets... can i use the custom tool to call REST management API to perform same.

Is that Recommended? any PROS or CONS

Comment: @Srav yes you can use a custom tool to call API via REST. Only CON I think of is how to refresh the shared access token that we generate for you.

Comment: Can't i use the approach stated to programatically create access token
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798668.aspx#ProgrammaticallyCreateToken

Thank you for your help!

Comment: FWIW, I had the same question and ended up writing a bash shell script to perform a bunch of curl commands to do this. For me, shell scripts are more portable since half of my team is on Mac and half on Windows.